# Laravel Database design and Eloquent query bottleneck

Tags: laravel, database-design, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship

I have designed a workout routine. This workout routine has a duration of 3 weeks and each week has 7 days. In these 7 days of each week, 3 of the 7 are rest days and each of the exercise days have  multiple exercises. My problem here is how do I link the weeks, days and exercises. I am able to add exercise to days. I am also able to able to link the days to weeks but how to i link these to the exact workout id considering that Workout - Weeks has a many-to-many relationship, Week - Days has a many-to-many relationship and Days - Exercises has a many-to-many relationship.

Please find my store function implementation below

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'title'             =>  'required|unique:workouts',
                'description'       =>  'required',
                'goal_id'           =>  'required',
                'level_id'          =>  'required',
                'duration'          =>  'required',
                'status'            =>  'required'
            ]);
            
            if($request->hasFile('image')) {
                // Upload an image file to cloudinary with one line of code
                $image = Cloudinary::upload($request->file('image')->getRealPath())->getSecurePath();
            }

            $workouts = Workout::create([
                'title'             =>  $request->title,
                'description'       =>  $request->description,
                'goal_id'           =>  $request->goal_id,
                'level_id'          =>  $request->level_id,
                'duration'          =>  $request->duration,
                'image'             =>  $image,
                'price'             =>  $request->price,
                'status'            =>  $request->status
            ]);

            $workouts->workout_bodypart()->sync($request->bodyparts);
            $workouts->workout_equipment()->sync($request->equipments);

            $weeks = array();
            for($i = 1; $i <= $request->duration; $i++) {
                $weeks[] = $i;
                $workouts->workout_week()->sync($weeks);
            }

            for($j = 1; $j <= $request->duration; $j++) {
                $weekDayWorkout = collect($request->week_.$j.'_day_1')->map(function($workouts) {
                    return ['workout_id' => $workouts->id];
                });

                dd($weekDayWorkout);

                Week::find($j)->week_day_1()->sync(
                    $weekDayWorkout
                ); 


                // Week::find($j)->week_day_2()->sync($request->week_.$j.'_day_2', ['workout_id' => $workouts->id]); 
                // Week::find($j)->week_day_3()->sync($request->week_.$j.'_day_3', ['workout_id' => $workouts->id]); 
                // Week::find($j)->week_day_4()->sync($request->week_.$j.'_day_4', ['workout_id' => $workouts->id]); 
                // Week::find($j)->week_day_5()->sync($request->week_.$j.'_day_5', ['workout_id' => $workouts->id]); 
                // Week::find($j)->week_day_6()->sync($request->week_.$j.'_day_6', ['workout_id' => $workouts->id]); 
                // Week::find($j)->week_day_7()->sync($request->week_.$j.'_day_7', ['workout_id' => $workouts->id]);  
            }

            if($workouts) {
                return redirect()->route('workouts.index')->with('success', 'Workout added successfully!');
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Something went wrong');
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the question about how to create a many-to-many relationship in laravel?

Comment: Not exactly so because as you can see, I already have some knowledge about doing that. However, the complexity of what I'm trying to achieve is why I have asked the question and shown my approach to achieving. I need guidance and/or corrections.

Comment: I'm sorry, in this case I do not really understand your question and what input / guidance you would like us to give! Is there anything wrong with the code in the question?